# Convert decimals to number and fraction

Tags: r, fractions

How can I convert decimal answers, e.g. `3353/6` into `558 5/6`?

`fractions(3353/6)` gets me 558.8333 but not in the fraction term. Is there any in-built function for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does the basic calculation you need:

```r
nicefrac <- function(x) {
   f <- attr(MASS::fractions(x), "fracs") ## extract string representation
   s <- as.numeric(strsplit(f, "/")[[1]])
   res <- c(whole = s[1] %/% s[2], num = s[1] %% s[2], denom = s[2])
   res
}
```

```r
x <- 3353/6
nicefrac(x)
## whole   num denom 
##   558     5     6
```

Depending on how you want to print/represent this, you could (1) leave it as-is; (2) use `sprintf("%d %d/%d", nicefrac[1], nicefrac[2], nicefrac[3])` to convert to a string representation; (3) write a little S3 class with a `print` method that does what you want (modifying `MASS:::print.fractions`).